# Sp_helptext Error

Tags: sql-server

I am using sp_helptext to list some stored procs instead of going through the ui. I am having a problem with the naming convention we have chosen to adopt.

I have a stored proc nameed [Test.FooBar].

```
Execute sp_helptext [Test.FooBar]
```

> Msg 15009, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 54 The
>   object 'Test.FooBar' does not exist in
>   database 'Foo' or is invalid for this
>   operation.

When I change the exceut statement to be fully qualified i get a different error

```
Execute sp_helptext [Foo].[dbo].[Test.FooBar]
```

> ```
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.
> ```

Can one someone point me in the right direction to fix this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
EXEC Foo..sp_helptext 'dbo.[Test.FooBar]';
```

Still having problems with sp_helptext? Ok, stop using it - it's not the only way to get the object's definition.

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.[Test.FooBar]'));
```

Next, please stop putting . and other special characters within object names.

Comment: I think that second suggestion is the more important one ...

Comment: How to get around the 8k limit of output for large db objects from the sqlcmd command line and not via ssms?

Comment: @Gary Powershell? Convert to XML? I mean if you have stored procedures that are > 8K and sqlcmd can't show > 8K, I'm not sure what you can do. [I published a tip about this that you might find readworthy](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I was hoping this might have been solved by now.  I prefer to mostly use the sqlcmd cli but dumping from ssms for large source is still the only way then.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying the below?

```
sp_helptext 'Test.FooBar'
```

Comment: Single and double qoutes still throw the invalid operation error

Comment: Can you tell us SELECT @@version? The code I gave above works perfectly on a SQL Server 2005 SP3 box. Even the [] works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Sankar Reddy: do you have a stored proc called test.foobar, or did it work for another stored proc?

Comment: Is Test.Foobar as stored procedure/function/View or a table? Can you check object type select * from sys.objects where name 'Foobar'

Comment: @gbn works for both

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (Intel X86)   May 26 2009 14:24:20   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

Comment: foobar is a stored procedure

Comment: Can be safely assumed that since this is Express, there is some sort of restriction put on which will not make this work?

Comment: I have tried this on a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition and it works fine. I don't expect this as a Express edition limitation as the engine is same between express & other editions. Have you tried creating a new schema & procedure, see if it works?

Comment: no, i Think i have put all the effort into this that I want to. Thank you for the help

Comment: That exact syntax works in SQL Server 2012.